# Create directory programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I want to create a directory inside my applicationSupportDirectory. My understanding is that the applicationSupportDirectory does not allow users to see the data within. This is why I have chosen it. However, the code I am using below seems to fail and I am not sure why.

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong? Thanks!

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *applicationDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get directory
NSString *dataPath = [applicationDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"drawings"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]){

NSError* error;
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error])
  ;// success
else
{
  NSLog(@"Failed");
}
}
}
```

Comment: pls change withIntermediateDirectories: is "YES"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *directoryName = @"drawing";

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *applicationDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePathAndDirectory = [applicationDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryName];
NSError *error;

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathAndDirectory
                               withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                attributes:nil
                                                     error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
}
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 6):

Try this one, it works for me.

```
NSString* documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                              NSUserDomainMask,
                                                              YES)[0];
NSString *folder = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foldername"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:folder]){
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:folder
           withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                            attributes:nil
                                 error:&error];
}
```

Comment: this answer is actually better. It only creates the directory if it doesn't exist. Thumbs up!

Answer (score -1):

To create Dirtectory

```
NSError *error;
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Application Support/directoryname"];
NSLog(@"%@",path);
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
    // Set do not backup attribute to whole folder

}
```